# Excel (cutting across workbooks)

Tags: excel, vba

I have three workbooks, A, B, and C.

A has a list of names indicating those I should move from B to C.

I am writing a macro inside A to do this. I just want to open/reference B and C, and be able to scan everything in A against everything in B, and any time I come across a match, cut the row from B and append to the end of C.

I am running into problems just getting the workbooks to be opened/referenced properly, let alone everything else

for example I am trying this to get the last row in C to use but it's giving me trouble

```
path = "C:\MyPath\"

bBath= path & "B.xls"
cPath= path & "C.xls"

Set bBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(bPath)
Set cBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(cPath)

k = 1
While cBook.Sheets("SomeSheetName").Row(k, 1) <> ""
    k = k + 1
Wend
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
k = 1
While cBook.Sheets("SomeSheetName").Row(k, 1) <> ""
    k = k + 1
Wend
```

With

```
k = cBook.Sheets("SomeSheetName").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

That will give you the last row where there is data / formatting on a sheet.

If you need the column to be absolute, you can do this

```
k = cBook.Sheets("SomeSheetName").Cells(cBook.Sheets("SomeSheetName").Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
```

for example would give you the last row used in column 1. Change the ,1 to ,2 for B and so on.
(you can clean that up a bit so its easier to read)

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't let me do cBook.sheets() to begin with. It gives me an object-error.

Comment: in that case most likely your path is wrong. An object-error means there is no object set - a workbook is an Object. So, when it tries to  Set cBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(cPath) it can't, because cPath is not recognized. Check that path is a correct string and that the file name is also correct and in that path. Seems obvious, but these things happen all the time, seemingly unexpectedly.

Comment: I just set it up on my system and ran your code. works smoooove

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was because I was using Row(k, 1) when I meant to use Cells(k,1). Set the rest of it up and works fine now (the paths were OK).

Comment: good call. I can't believe I didn't see that either! But still, it's more efficient to use the methods I provided, than to do the looping you did. While it works essentially, it's taking up a considerable amount of more time. You want notice it on small data sets, but after a few thousands rows... boy oh boy!

Answer (score 1):

Change row(k,1) to cells(k,1).